# How to iterate over db records correctly with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, batch-processing

I want to iterate over records in the database and update them. However since that updating is both taking some time and prone to errors, I need to a) don't keep the db waiting (as e.g. with a `ScrollableResults`) and b) commit after each update.
Second thing is that this is done in multiple threads, so I need to ensure that if thread A is taking care of a record, thread B is getting another one.
How can I implement this sensibly with hibernate?

To give a better idea, the following code would be executed by several threads, where all threads share a single instance of the `RecordIterator`:

```
Iterator<Record> iter = db.getRecordIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Record rec = iter.next();
    // do something lengthy here
    db.save(rec);
}
```

So my question is how to implement the `RecordIterator`. If on every `next()` I perform a query, how to ensure that I don't return the same record twice? If I don't, which query to use to return detached objects? Is there a flaw in the general approach (e.g. use one `RecordIterator` per thread and let the db somehow handle synchronization)? Additional info: there are way to many records to locally keep them (e.g. in a set of treated records).

**Update:** Because the overall process takes some time, it can happen that the status of Records changes. Due to that the ordering of the result of a query can change. I guess to solve this problem I have to mark records in the database once I return them for processing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, what about pushing your objects from a reader thread in some bounded blocking queue, and let your updater threads read from that queue.

In your reader, do some paging with setFirstResult/setMaxResults. E.g. if you have 1000 elements maximum in your queue, fill them up 500 at a time. When the queue is full, the next push will automatically wait until the updaters take the next elements.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. I am Sorry, but I didn't think of another problem which I described in the update to the question. I guess to solve this problem I have to mark records in the database once I return them for processing...

Comment: I did something similar in the past. What I ended up doing was indeed creating a marker table that stored those entries that were updated. I was using Spring Batch BTW to handle the queing and paging.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be, since you're sharing an instance of the master iterator, is to run all of your threads using a shared Hibernate transaction, with one load at the beginning and a big save at the end.  You load all of your data into a single 'Set' which you can iterate over using your threads (be careful of locking, so you might want to split off a section for each thread, or somehow manage the shared resource so that you don't overlap).

The beauty of the Hibernate solution is that the records aren't immediately saved to the database, since you're using a transaction, and are stored in hibernate's cache.  Then at the end they'd all be written back to the database at once.  This would save on those expensive database writes you're worried about, plus it gives you an actual object to work with on each iteration, instead of just a database row.

I see in your update that the status of the records may change during processing, and this could always cause a problem.  If this is a constantly running process or long running, then my advice using a hibernate solution would be to work in smaller sets, and yes, add a flag to mark records that have been updated, so that when you move to the next set you can pick up ones that haven't been touched.

Comment: This was my initial idea. However, it has some serious drawbacks:
a) If I encounter any errors (which is likely in my scenario), all intermediate results are lost. b) All data-validating is done at the end, so if I create any inconsistencies, I will only notice after all results are calculated AND lost (see a)). c) I will run into memory problems, since I need to keep ALL records in memory until the final commit.